# How to define correct path to files php js and json

Tags: javascript, php

I've bootstrap dashboard and now I need to rewrite to my codeigniter 3 admin panel app.

My address url  strcuture:  `https://myadmin.com/admin`

I've put `assets` folder in `root public_html`

and Now when I call script in footer:

```
<script src="assets/js/pages/api-key.init.js"></script>
```

then I have error 404 because function try open file in path:

`https://myadmin.com/admin/assets/js/pages/api-key.init.js`

but correct path is:

`https://myadmin.com/assets/js/pages/api-key.init.js`

the next problem script `api-key.init.js` have content and try open another path:

```
assets/json/api-key-list.json
```

and in `api-key-list.json` I have another path example to images:

```
assets/img/avatar-1.jpg
```

**issue describe:**

how can I define in all these files like footer php/html  .js and .json to search for these files instead of constantly opening each file individually and giving the full address with domain name?

example in footer I can give:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/pages/api-key.init.js"></script>
```

but when in .js file I cannot give  because .js files not read this variable and im not sure how to correct resolve because due to this I;ve most issues and most functions in dashboard not working correct and I need spend more time to debug and step by step check in log console and change path.

Comment: Use `/assets/js/pages/api-key.init.js` instead of `assets/js/pages/api-key.init.js`. This will start looking for your assets from the toplevel of your webserver's document root.

Comment: This should also working  in .js /assets/json/api-key-list.json  and in .json /assets/img/avatar-1.jpg  ?